# How to scroll down a twitter page to load next pages and extract the data

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, scroll, scrape

**I am trying to scroll down comments on a twitter status,trying to extract the page with all the comments(or at least first 5 pages). Using selenium driver for it , but not successful with the scrolling part, so i have to do manually and extract. I am using python 3.6.5 Pls help...**

for eg for this tweet - https://twitter.com/TeamYouTube/status/1012415985184206848
Can anyone help me with code..

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="...../chromedriver")
driver.get('https://twitter.com/TeamYouTube/status/1012415985184206848')

for i in range(1,10):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(3)

ip = input("Enter y to proceed: ")
if(ip == 'y'):
    page = driver.page_source
    filename = input('Enter file name : ')
    path = 'D:/page_'+filename+'.html'
    f = open(path,'w',encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(page)
f.close()
driver.close()
```

Comment: time.sleep(3) will create issues for slower network connection if all set of comments are not loaded

Comment: `but not successful with the scrolling part` what does it mean? What exactly is wrong? Stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);", driver.findElement(By.id("#permalink-overlay-dialog")));
```

**Explanation:** you have to scroll a particular `div`. To be able to do it, you have to find this element on the page and the scroll to the end of the page only this element.

Second suggestion is to use:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
# locate element and simulate 'END' button press
driver.find_element_by_id("permalink-overlay-dialog").send_keys(Keys.END)
```

if ot won't work try also to extend with ActionChains:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = driver.find_element_by_id("permalink-overlay-dialog")
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(element).perform()
element.send_keys(Keys.END)
```